# How to create users on a LDAP server with Perl for Unix authentication?

Tags: perl, unix, ldap

I'm trying to create a web server which needs for some user authentication within the server itself. I need to do it with Perl so I decided to try to use an LDAP server in localhost.

I've been trying to use the script below. Everything is configured correctly (as i tried to search for entries aready configured), but, when I try to run the script, it tells me "Index generation failed"

```perl
my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new( '127.0.0.1' ) or die "$@";

my $mesg = $ldap->bind ('cn=admin, dc=ramal, dc=com',
                        password=>'<admin_password>'
                     );

#$mesg->code or die $mesg->error;

my $result = $ldap->add('uid=pruebaPerl, ou=User, dc=ramal, dc=com',
                        attrs=> [
                                'uid' => 'pruebaPerl',
                                'cn' => 'Usuario de prueba de Perl',
                                'objectclass' => ['account', 'posixAccount', 'shadowAccount'],
                                'userPassword' => '<hashed password>',
                                'loginShell' => '/bin/bash',
                                'uidNumber' => 2001,
                                'gidNumber' => 2001,
                                'homeDirectory' => '/home/pruebaPerl'
                        ]
                );

$result->code and warn "Failed to add entry: ", $result->error;

$mesg = $ldap->unbind
```

So, I think something's wrong in the arguments for add but I don't know what.
Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Is the password hash real?

Comment: @choroba yes, sorry, the passwords were all real, already edited them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely an issue on the `slapd` side. Not a `perl` issue.

This old thread https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200407/msg00007.html suggests that maybe your test ldap structure got created wrong using slapadd  instead of using ldapadd.
Or you have a permission issue.

Have you tried `strace` 'ing the slapd process ?

Also try to remove the spaces in `'uid=pruebaPerl, ou=User, dc=ramal, dc=com' and 'cn=admin, dc=ramal, dc=com'`

Comment: I've tried running the program with root priviledges and also removing the spaces, but none of the solutions worked. How can I enable the strace'ing of the slapd process?

Comment: After doing some research it seems you were right and the ldap structure got corrupted somewhere with slapadd  and, after restoring, it works so thanks!